# How can I use clone brush in the UV/Image editor?

Tags: interface, texture-painting

I am using a clone brush on a model using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> to define origin of the clone brush. Why it doesn't work when I'm doing the same in UV/Image Editor?

Answer (score 9):

I'll show you the method, which does not work exactly like the one you mentioned (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Mouse Click</kbd>) but may be useful for you.

In *Uv/Image Editor* change the *Mode* to ***Paint***.
[image]

Place the cursor in the *Uv/Image Editor* window and press <kbd>T</kbd>. It will display the *Tools panel* on the left. Choose the clone brush and an image, which will be the source for cloning.
[image]

Place the image wherever you want holding the <kbd>Right Mouse Click</kbd>. Paint by pressing the <kbd>Left Mouse Click</kbd>.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that may be a temporary solution, its not very intuitive for inexperienced users, would be nice to have the clone option like in photoshop or other image editors.

Comment: For some reason I do not have Blend type option in clone brush.

Comment: Note: It can happen that the clone image is not visible, because it is positioned far away, zoom out too find it.