# Can I paint a texture within the UV viewport?

Tags: uv

Is there a way to draw something within the UV viewport and not the 3d viewport?

Comment: Related answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27552/how-can-i-use-clone-brush-in-the-uv-image-editor

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In *Uv Editor* switch the *Mode* to ***Paint***. Open a *Tools panel* (<kbd>T</kbd>) and select a brush.

[image]

Now you can paint. 
Remember to save your image when you're done with painting (*Image-->Save As Image*). When you see a little star (*) next to the *Image* in header it means that the image isn't saved.

[image]

Here are some useful shortcuts that can be used in a *UV Editor* window:

- press <kbd>S</kbd> to pick a color sample
- hold <kbd>S</kbd> and press LMB to add a color sample to your palette (you may also do it pressing a <kbd>+</kbd> button located under the circular color palette).

[image]

- press <kbd>F</kbd> to change the size of a brush
- press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to change the strenght of a brush

After pressing the shortcuts you may also change the attributes of a brush using numerical keyboard buttons.

[image]

- press <kbd>E</kbd> to change the stroke method

Here you can find many interesting options (like a *Curve* stroke- very useful for precise painting).

[image]

- press <kbd>X</kbd> to quickly flip the color slots

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the mode of the UV/Image Editor.
Switch it to Paint Mode.
You can change the color in the tools-window.

[image]