# UV image editor, only drawing straight lines

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

[image: blender interface with UV Image Editor and 3D view]

I think that accidentally I pressed some key, and now all I can draw is straight lines in this way.
I'm using a digital tablet, the other texture in this same scene paints correctly.
I don't know what function I pressed, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem was the image texture resolution that i was using. (like 4000x4000 that was the problem), I scale that image to 1024*1024 and the brush work correctly. I was aware of the "stroke method", but there was not the problem, since it was in "space".

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you accidentaly changed the *paint stroke method* to ***Line***. Press <kbd>E</kbd> in the *UV Editor* window and change it to ***Space*** or do it in the *Paint Stroke* panel.

For other useful shortcuts please see this answer: [Can I paint a texture within the UV viewport?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/can-i-paint-a-texture-within-the-uv-viewport)
[image]

Comment: really thanks man, but I found that the problem was the image texture resolution that i was using. (like 4000x4000), I scale that image to 1024*1024 and the brush work correctly.  I was aware of the "stroke method", but there was not the problem, since it was in "space".