# Effective ways to paint textures

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I would like tips or tutorials for how to paint good looking textures. I don’t own Photoshop and aren’t planning to buy it yet. So are there any free software that works good for painting textures or are there more simple ways to do it in Blender? Right now I’ve painted them in Blender, but in case there is’nt some workflow I don’t know about I would say it is’nt effective or easy. Especially when it comes to details. I have used either texture paint to paint straight on the object or image editor and painted on the image. It seems most convenient to paint on the image rather than on the object, however it can be hard to know where it will end up on the object. I aint experienced with creating textures, so any help is appreciated. Also, I am using 2.8 beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use it, [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) is a great alternative to Photoshop with a lot of the same tools and features for free. From there you could probably follow a Photoshop tutorial relatively well like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCvEbV-LYyY).

I don't do it as much any more, but when I did texture painting, it worked really well for me to have a texture paint window open on one side of my display and an image editor on the other (see [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/can-i-paint-a-texture-within-the-uv-viewport)). Doing this, you can get some really good detail as long as you have a good set of [UVs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k). I never even had to use GIMP or Photoshop.

Comment: *Krita* can be efficiency as well iif the painting is mainly using layer and paint effect with stylus input

Comment: Yes Krita seems to be the reference now