# How can I copy part of a texture to another part of the same texture?

Tags: texture-painting

Specifically I have an object that is symmetrical in shape, so the UVs are the same and I would like to copy part of the texture to another place of the UV map so that I can put in different details on each of them but use the same starting textures. Here's a screenshot to help clarify what I'm wanting to copy.

[image]

Comment: you can probably go in paint mode and use a clone brush, see also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27552/how-can-i-use-clone-brush-in-the-uv-image-editor

Answer (score 1):

Activate the Magic UV addon

After unwrapping the mesh

Select a single face and set the face with the uv texture.

Press U and you get the extra option with UV Magic Addon below

Select Copy/Paste UV -> Copy UV- Default

Then select the face you want to paste or face with similar texture on other 
side

Press U

Select Copy/Paste UV -> Paste UV- Default

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem right, but maybe I misunderstand. I want to copy the texture, and then change the texture afterwards. This seems to be using exactly the same texture, which isn't what I want to end up with. I'll try playing with the UV Magic addon in the mean time.

Comment: with the L key u can select the uv and move where u need it

Comment: I don't want to move the UV, I want to copy part of the texture.

Answer (score 1):

First, set your UV Image Editor to 'Paint' and then choose the Clone tool instead of TexDraw.[image: 1 clone] Then set the clone image as the one you are painting so you can use it as a texture to paint with, and move it to position with rmb.[image: set clone image] Paint at full power to clone the pixels into the new position from the repositioned image. [image: paint full power]Turn off the clone source and then save the image progress.[image: save image]